# killing an activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity, kill

Since my class could not inherit Activity class, I used context.startActivity() to launch a new activity. In this type of launch, how can kill the launched activity.? How can i use finish() in this circumstance?

Comment: You need to kill your activity from somewhere else ( not from the activity you want to kill ). Is that right

Comment: In my class which doesnt inherit Activity, i created an activity. Now i want to kill it. May the very next statement is to kill it. The problem is,since  the class doesnt inherit Activity, i cant use finish(). What are the different ways of doing it..?

Comment: If my answer is helpful to you then please do accept it as it will also increase your reputation on StackOverflow and more people will answer your questions in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this type of launch, how can kill the launched activity.?

You don't.

> How can i use finish() in this circumstance?

You don't. One activity does not finish another activity in general.

> May the very next statement is to kill it.

Since the new activity will not have been displayed by the time of "very next statement", then you should not have started it in the first place.

Comment: Okay say after some condition is satisfied, how can I kill the Activity?

Comment: @Kishan: The new activity that you launched can kill *itself* via `finish()` when "some condition is satisfied". Your original activity should be doing absolutely nothing while the new activity is in the foreground.

Comment: @commonsWare- but just like v kill an activity( when the class inherits Activity )using finish() function, v should also be able or ther should be some way of killing it without Activity class inherited right...?

Comment: @Kishan: "but just like v kill an activity" -- I have no idea what "v" is, besides being the 23rd letter in the English alphabet.

Comment: @commonsWare- Sorry its just a short cut for "we". I want the launcher activity itself to kill the activity it created....

Comment: @Kishan: Your launcher cannot, should not, and will not "kill the activity it created".

Answer (score 2):

If you started a new activity to get some result then you should use `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()`.

and if you want to stop an activity after performing some necessary tasks then call `finish()` at the end of the `onCreate()` after performing everything necessary.

and if you have something else in your mind then let me know. I will try my level best to help you.

Comment: Thanks. I could use finish() method at the end, but my class doesnt inherit Activity class which is necessary to invoke finish(). This is the problem.

Comment: In this case you do not need to end it as it won't be treated as an activity by dalvik. Treat your class just like a normal java class. Instantiate it, use it and if you want then you can destroy the instance in the end otherwise garbage collection will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to just pass contex object from LAUNCHER activity's onCreate method.

You may use below code.

`public Class ABc{

```
         Contex co;
         ABc(Contex con){
               co=con;
          }
       con.startActivity(intent);
```

}`

And `onCreate` method create object of this `ABc` class.

Comment: Ya this is what i have done, but how can i kill the Activity you created in your code...? (in launcher Activity)

Comment: you can use con.finish(); in the class.